# Changing visibility of <li> elements on hover

Tags: jquery, css, visibility, show-hide

I have a navbar `ul` with icons and another `ul` aligned in a fixed position to appear next to it with a label for each icon. When the user hovers over a `li` in the navbar, I want the corresponding `li` in the second `ul` to become visible, then become hidden again when the cursor leaves.

I have tried CSS solutions using :hover and jQuery ones using `.show()` and `.hide()`, but for some reason it isn't happening.

HTML:

```html
<ul id="vnav">
   <li id="vis"><a class="vnavlink" href="#1"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-eye-open"  aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Vision"></span></a></li>
   <li id="val"><a class="vnavlink" href="#2"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok"  aria-hidden="true" aria-label="2"></span></a></li>
   <li id="foo"><a class="vnavlink" href="#3"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="3"></span></a></li>
   <li id="dri"><a class="vnavlink" href="#4"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="4"></span></a></li>
   <li id="eng"><a class="vnavlink" href="#5"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok"  aria-hidden="true" aria-label="5"></span></a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li class="vbox" id="visbox">Vision</li>
   <li class="vbox" id="valbox">v2</li>
   <li class="vbox" id="foobox">v3</li>
   <li class="vbox" id="dribox">v4</li>
   <li class="vbox" id="engbox">v5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
#vnav {
list-style-type: none; 
text-decoration: none; 
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:350px;
z-index:1;
}

#visbox {
left:95px;
top:368px;
}

.vbox {
position:fixed;
z-index:1;
height:40px;
width:120px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#vnav:hover + #vbox {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Alternatively, here is one of my attempts at using jQuery for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#visbox').hide();
});
```

(NB. I also tried setting the default in the CSS as `visibility:hidden` or `display:hidden`)

```js
$('#vis').hover(function(){
  $('#visbox').show();},
  function(){
  $('#visbox').hide();
});
```

Comment: I've tried to hack a fiddle together based on what you've given us: http://jsfiddle.net/axuj6089/ we obviously need more css. Two problems with your CSS attempt: `+` is the sibling selector and `vbox` is not a sibling of `#vnav`. Further more `vbox` is a class not an ID. Also try using `display:none` instead of `visability:hidden` and `display:block` instead of `visibility:visible;`. See this SO question for the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: Thanks Jon - I did put vbox as a class when I tried it; I just typed it out wrong here. I managed to get the same result as you have achieved here before with css, but what I want is for each icon (i.e. each <li>) to make just one label visible (i.e. just one <li> from the second <ul>), rather than the whole <ul> rendering the whole second <ul> visible on hover, as happens here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly (now ;-)) what you want to do (basicly show an label on mouseover) you are really trying it complicated.

I'd try not to fight with two `<ul>`s next to each other (which can get even more messy when you also would like to make everything responsive for example) but add the Icons to the main `<ul>` and only show them on `:hover`. That could look like something like this:

HTML:

```
 <ul>
   <li class="vbox" id="visbox"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-eye-open"></span> <span class="text-label">Vision</span></li>
   <li class="vbox" id="valbox"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok"></span> <span class="text-label">v2</span></li>
    <li class="vbox" id="foobox"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok"></span> <span class="text-label">v3</span></li>
   <li class="vbox" id="dribox"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok"></span> <span class="text-label">v4</span></li>
   <li class="vbox" id="engbox"><span class="glyphicon glyph2 glyphicon-ok"></span> <span class="text-label">v5</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.vbox{
    list-style: none;
}
.vbox .text-label {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.vbox:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vbox:hover .text-label {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

You can check out the behavior in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmonnj5n/1/ (and here is the old fiddle where the icons were hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmonnj5n/)
If this it what you wanted you need to adjust the position to your case because I stripped any positioning which is relevant to your specifc case.

**EDIT**
The icon now is always visible and what gets shown/hidden on mouseover/mouseout is the label.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jey. Unfortunately I was not looking to show the icon on mouseover, but rather to have the icons all visible but the second <ul> containing the labels invisible, then when the user hovers over any particular icon, the corresponding label becomes visible (i.e. the corresponding <li> from the second <ul>).

Comment: Okay, so when I understand you correctly now, it's just the other way around than before. You could use the same approach then and just give the text labels a class which you hide per default and show on `.vbox:hover`. I've updated my answer and my fiddle. See if that fits your needs.

Comment: That does the trick. I had actually just come up with a workaround where the second <ul> becomes a series of children of the first <ul>'s <li>s and then the css visibility can be applied to the child <ul>s. Your solution is much simpler and more elegant though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('#vnav .vnavlink').mouseover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent =  $(this).attr('id');
    $(".vbox").hide();
    $("#"+parent+"box").show();
}).mouseout(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent =  $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+parent+"box").hide();
})
```